# How to start Symfony built-in server?

Tags: php, symfony, server

I've been using Symfony Built-in server, but now when I use the command: `php bin/console server:start` it is not starting anymore. It says: `couldn't open input file : bin/console`. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: whats the status. di you try force . http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html

Comment: yes i've try it and it displayed the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following command:

```
php app/console server:run
```

Comment: i do it. but nothing happen

Answer (score 2):

Just use `app/console` instead of `bin/console`.

On the documentation page you can select your current Symfony version. In Symfony 3.0  `bin/console` is using. In early versions - `app/console`.

Compare: [Symfony 2.7 built-in web server](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html) and [Symfony 3.0 built-in web server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html).

Answer (score 0):

Symfony version 5.0: symfony server:start

Before: php bin/console server:run

Answer (score 0):

the error `couldn't open input file : bin/console` means that it cannot find the `bin` folder. 
two possiblities :

- you're not in the appropriate folder. Go to your application folder before executing any `php bin/console ...` command.
- you're using an <2.7 version of symfony and the command you'll need to use is `php app/console ...`

Answer (score 0):

With symfony 5.x, (probably 4.x, I did not check), enter
`symfony server:start` from your web application folder.

The symfony application can be reached in a browser with the URL returned by the command.